# C# DataTable.Select()

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

DataTable.Select("agent=98788") method is not returning any rows while agent 98788 is exsting in DataTable. Other agents are getting filtered, only having problem with this agent 98788. Any Idea why this number is not getting filtered using DataTable.Select() method?

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("agent", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("shiftdate", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("agentoid", typeof(string));
string sourceAgent = "98788";
string targetAgent = "881757";
dt.Rows.Add("98788","2017-10-27","");
dt.Rows.Add("881757", "2017-10-27", "");


DataRow[] drr1 = dt.Select("agent=" + sourceAgent + "");
DataRow[] drr2 = dt.Select("agent=" + targetAgent + "");
```

drr1 is empty while drr2 is not empty.
My confusion is why drr2 is not empty and drr1 is empty. Why "881757" is filterable but "98788" is not? C# .Select() method's behavior should be same for all cases, But in my case it seems it is behaving differently.
Is it a bug in DataTable.Select()?

Comment: I think its `DataTable.where(m => m.agent = 98788)`

Comment: That's not LINQ, just a regular data table method.

Comment: You have to show your code, otherwise we can't reproduce your issue and we can't help to fix it. I have filled a sample table with your column and value and your `Select`-expression worked. It worked if the column was a string and it worked when it was an `int`-column.

Comment: Can you try: DataTable.Select("agent=98788" OR agent='98788'")

Comment: Column `[agent]` is of `string` data type, and the value has a whitespace at the start/end? Dump your datatable to xml file using `DataTable.WriteXml` and look at it in a text editor

Comment: do you need double == or maybe quotes around the value? '98788'?

Comment: My confusion is why drr2 is not empty and drr1 is empty. Why "881757" is filterable but "98788" is not? .Select() method's behavior should be same for all cases, But in my case it seems it is behaving differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use single quotes to specify a filter on string values:

```
DataRow[] drr1 = dt.Select("agent='" + sourceAgent + "'");
DataRow[] drr2 = dt.Select("agent='" + targetAgent + "'");
```

More about DataView RowFilter Syntax:
http://www.csharp-examples.net/dataview-rowfilter/

Quote:

> **Literals**
>   String values are enclosed within single quotes ' '. If the string contains single quote ', the quote must be doubled.

Comment: My confusion is why drr2 is not empty and drr1 is empty. Why "881757" is filterable but "98788" is not?

Comment: Please clear my confusion OR its a bug in framework?

Comment: How expressions like these work internally is beyond my knowledge. If you really need to know more, search the web for `referencesource datatable.cs` and also `referencesource "class Select" filterExpression`, and be prepared to do a lot of digging...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion :)